# Phone and Tablet View for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

i'm triying to make a xaml that can be different in phone and tablet. I have something like this:

```
<OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="View">
    <OnIdiom.Phone>
        <ContentView VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            ...
            <LineEntry x:Name="User" Style="{StaticResource Style1}"/>
            ...
        </ContentView>
    </OnIdiom.Phone>
    <OnIdiom.Tablet>
        <ContentView VerticalOptions="End">
            ...
            <LineEntry x:Name="User" Style="{StaticResource Style2}"/>
            ...
        </ContentView>
    </OnIdiom.Tablet>
</OnIdiom>
```

But can't use the same id name in the codebehind. How can i do? i don't want to use 2 variables (for example userPhone and userTablet), for each platform. Is another way to accomplish that?  thx!

Comment: Use [OnIdiom Markupextension](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/XamarinForms-101-OnIdiom-Adjusting-UI-Based-on-Device-Type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most properties on an object can be altered using OnIdiom or OnPlatform.

```
<Image Aspect="AspectFit" x:Name="logoImg">
     <Image.HeightRequest>
          <OnPlatform Default="400" Android="350" />
     </Image.HeightRequest>
     <Image.IsVisible>
          <OnIdiom Default="True" Phone="False" />
     </Image.IsVisible>
</Image>
```

So in your example (not tested)

```
<ContentView>
   <ContentView.VerticalOptions>
      <OnIdiom Default="End" Phone="CenterAndExpand" />
   <ContentView.VerticalOptions>
</ContentView>
```